# Adjusting extra_x_range in bokeh according to the old x-range

Tags: plot, bokeh

I have added `extra_x_ranges` to my plot by:
`p.extra_x_ranges = {“range_hist_freq”: Range1d(start=2000, end=0)}`.

But I want the `0` of this new x-axis to be plotted just in front of some value in old x-axis. Here the old x-axis is in the datetime format. Is there a way I can do this?